# Using Controller to get data into mvc grid

Tags: c#, .net-core

I want to load mvc grid with data from controller:

Code:

GridView `dumasGrid`:

```
@model IEnumerable<BoneID.Dumas.Obroci>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "PopisObroka";
    WebGrid grid = new WebGrid(Model, ajaxUpdateContainerId: "tblGrid");
}

<div>
    @grid.GetHtml();
</div>
```

View page that load grid view page: `dumasGridPlaner`:

```
@using BoneID.Classes
@using BoneID.Net.Static
@model BoneID.Web.Models.ModelDefault
@{
    var isIzoProd = Model.ParametriEx.Any(a => a.Type == CParametriEx.ParametriExType.IzoProd);
}

<div>
    @Html.Partial("dumasGrid");
</div>
```

Main page that load page with grid: `Dumas`

```
<div id="tabs-1">                                     
    @Html.Partial("dumasGridPlaner",Model.Default)
</div>
```

My controller:

```
namespace BoneID.Web.Client.Controllers
{
    public class DumasController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [ChildActionOnly]
        public ActionResult PopisObroka()
        {
            Obroci obr = new Obroci();
            var menu = obr.GetObroci();
            return PartialView(menu);
        }
    }
}
```

Error that I get on page `DumasGridPlaner`:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'BoneID.Web.Models.ModelDefault', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[BoneID.Dumas.Obroci]'

What is the problem? What am I calling wrong?

Comment: I don't think you have given us enough code to point the root of error, however, this error comes when you are passing an object of the wrong type to your view. Here your view is expecting `IEnumerable<BoneID.Dumas.Obroci>` as a model but you may be passing something else.

Comment: I agree with @Priyank. We need more information to understand your MVC structure and how you are sending your model to your view?

Comment: Dumas.cshtml is my main shared view page where I'm calling other views and Controlller. There is no other pages.

Comment: You are passing data inside a partial view and also it's not clear why you are using 2 partial views to pass this data. I think you need just a simple view or a viewcomponent to pass your data.

Comment: In your 'dumasGridPlaner' when calling `@Html.Partial("dumasGrid")` you are not passing any model, whereas 'dumasGrid' is expecting `IEnumerable<BoneID.Dumas.Obroci>`

Comment: the problem is that I have to use two models in one view that I can't. Grid is using model IEnumerable<BoneID.Dumas.Obroci> but gridPLaner is using BoneID.Web.Models.ModelDefault. I don't know how to combine those two.

Comment: Can you show us your models please?

Comment: I managed to solve the problem. instead of model I used using...

Comment: Now the problem is that ienumerable list has sorted columns by name.
I don't want that, i want the columns to be as my select statement.
How to remove column sort?